C# WPF recursive duplicate nested hierarchy of elements
I have created treeview with dynamically filled from xml file hierarchy and I have issue. In treeview nested hierarchy was recursive duplicate and get result like this :

XAML-markup of treeview:
<TreeView x:Name="leftNestingTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Fragments, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildFragments}" DataType="{x:Type a:FragmentModel}">
            <TextBlock  Text = "{Binding fragmentId}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

Code of source:
Fragments = NestingTree.Values.ToList();
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Fragments));

XML file:
<NestingTree>
  <fragment id="root_fragment" name=" n1">
    <parent id="" name="" />
    <childs count="1">
      <child id="f1" name="frag1" />
    </childs>
  </fragment>
    <fragment id="f1" name="frag1">
    <parent id="root_fragment" name="n1" />
    <childs count="1">
      <child id="f2" name="frag2" />
    </childs>
  </fragment>
  <fragment id="f2" name="frag2">
    <parent id="f1" name="frag1" />
    <childs count="0" />
  </fragment>
</NestingTree>

UPDATE
NestingTree is Dictionary<string,FragmentModel>, where keys is ids and values is fragments.
Code of FragmentModel:
public class FragmentModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string fragmentId { get; set; }    
    private string fragmentName { get; set; }    
    public string FragmentName
    {
        get { return fragmentName; }
        set 
        { 
           fragmentName = value; 
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FragmentName)); 
        }
     }
     public FragmentModel ParentFragment { get; set; }
     public List<FragmentModel> ChildFragments { get; set; }                   
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
     {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
            PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
     }
}

Filling of NestingTree data from XML file:
XDocument xmlNestingTree = XDocument.Load("nesting_tree.xml");
if (xmlNestingTree.Element("NestingTree") is not null)
{
   int count = 0;
   foreach (XElement fragment in 
    xmlNestingTree.Element("NestingTree").Elements("fragment"))
   {
       string id = fragment.Attribute("id").Value;
       FragmentModel f = new FragmentModel
       {
           fragmentId = id,
           FragmentName = fragment.Attribute("name").Value,
       };
       nestingTree.Add(id, f);
   }
   foreach (XElement fragment in 
     xmlNestingTree.Element("NestingTree").Elements("fragment"))
   {
        FragmentModel currentFragment = nestingTree.Values.Where(f => f.fragmentId == fragment.Attribute("id").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        FragmentModel parentFragment = nestingTree.Values.Where(f => f.ChildFragments.Contains(currentFragment)).FirstOrDefault();
        currentFragment.ParentFragment = parentFragment; 
        if (Int32.TryParse(fragment.Element("childs").Attribute("count").Value, out count) && count > 0)
        {
            foreach (XElement child in fragment.Element("childs").Elements("child"))
            {
                FragmentModel currentChildFragment = nestingTree.Values.Where(f => f.fragmentId == child.Attribute("id").Value).FirstOrDefault();  
                currentFragment
                    .ChildFragments
                    .Add(currentChildFragment);
            }
        }
    }
    NestingTree = nestingTree;
}


There is obviously a problem with populating the source collection, i.e. the NestingTree Dictionary(?). Please show the code where you are doing that. Also show the relevant parts of the FragmentModel declaration.

Thank you very much for your comments. I have added changes based on them. I have already checked this point before, but I did not find anything that could cause such behavior of the program.

This looks confusing. Why are you using a Dictionary when you do not make use of it? For example, an expression like nestingTree.Values.Where(f => f.fragmentId == fragment.Attribute("id").Value).FirstOrDefault(); should actually be nestingTree.TryGetValue(fragment.Attribute("id").Value, out FragmentModel currentFragment).

It is also unclear why FragmentModel has a PropertyChanged event and an OnPropertyChanged method when it does not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. And why would it implement that interface at all? Does the FragmentName property ever change?

Also, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. It has no effect on a OneWay Binding like this.

Oh thanks. Didn't notice about that INotifyPropertyChanged. FragmentName cant change at now because its not implemented. I`m grateful for you comments)

You should also fix the XML. It does not seem to make sense to have fragment elements with parent and childs (which would correctly be called children) at the same time, since this is redundant information. A parent id would be sufficient, assuming that ids are unique.

The parent id would also be an attribute, not a tag, since <parent id="f1" name="frag1" /> also contains redundant name information.

It is also unclear why you would not directly store the tree structure in XML.

It`s because fragments need additional processing before storing in oringinal code. XML structure would be changed. Thank you)

Possible approaches of saving tree data are:

store linear list of items, where each item contains "parent_id" attribute
store list of children directly in each element.

Your xml uses both approaches in the same time.
I'd suggest to remove 'parent_id' (code will recursively read each xml element and build tree)
or
remove 'children' (in this case code will read all elements to list and build tree by levels, first search root fragment(s) with no parent, then loop by fond list and search fragments whose parent is current item, etc).
Here is example of second approach:
Read a XML tree structure recursively in a List<T> with children lists<T>

Thank you very much! This link helps me a lot)
